# How to reference domain specific asset path in multi domain multi env setup?

Tags: multi-environment, multi-domain

I have a site setup for Craft 3 like below
.env variables for development
local
staging 
production

Folder structure is standard.
My assest volumes are like below.

```
'@assetBaseUrl/documents/xx'
'@assetBaseUrl/web/assets/documents/xx'
```

I need to add a new site on separate domain which i have done in Craft control site manager. For the moment its called "awards"

I added domain specific variables to .env like:

```
CRAFTENV_BASE_URL_AWARDS = "https://awards.com/"
CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH_AWARDS = "/mypath/"
ASSET_BASE_URL_AWARDS="https://awards.com/assets"
ASSET_BASE_PATH_AWARDS="/mypathft3/public_html/assets/awards"
```

My config file only references asset paths for domain 1 from the .env file.  For example:

```
    'baseUrl'  => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL'),
    'basePath' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH'),
    'aliases' => [
        '@assetBaseUrl' => getenv('ASSET_BASE_URL'),
        '@assetBasePath' => getenv('ASSET_BASE_PATH'),
        '@baseUrl' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_URL'),
        '@basePath' => getenv('CRAFTENV_BASE_PATH')
    ],
```

I am using the same templates folder for domain 2 as domain 1 and craft is finding this OK with my one basic section:

```
/templates/<sitename2>/
```

SO my question is how do i achieve separation of assets volumes for domain 2?
Do i use domain 2 specific env variables in asset folder paths that can read my .env domain specific vars then use these in new volumes?

What if I want to share volumes across sites?

Been baking my noodle for hours